# Lambda expression in list.erase

Tags: c++, list, lambda, stdlist

I'm learning lambdas and am trying various examples, and I'm not sure I see why this doesn't work:

```
std::list<int> listIntegers;
listIntegers.push_back(40);

listIntegers.erase([listIntegers]() {
return std::find(listIntegers.begin(), listIntegers.end(), 40);
});
```

I also tried to write explicitely:

```
listIntegers.erase([listIntegers]()->std::list<int>::const_iterator {
    return std::find(listIntegers.begin(), listIntegers.end(), 40);
    });
```

However this of course works:

```
auto found40Iterator = std::find(listIntegers.begin(), listIntegers.end(), 40)

listIntegers.erase(found40Iterator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case of

```
listIntegers.erase([listIntegers]()->std::list<int>::const_iterator {
    return std::find(listIntegers.begin(), listIntegers.end(), 40);
});
```

The capture list `[listIntegers]` is taking `listInteger` by value, a copy is stored with the lambda. Since the `listIntegers` used in `std::find(listIntegers.begin(), listIntegers.end(), 40)` is a copy of the original, it will find element `40` within that copy. The returned iterator is therefore an iterator to the element in the copy and not in the original. Iterators can only be used with other iterators from the same container and with their original container. The problem you are seeing is that your lambda's return value is being used with `listIntegers` but it actually refers to an element in a different range (the copy of `listIntegers`).

The solution is to change your capture list to take `listIntegers` by reference, so that it will operate on the original `listIntegers`. There is also the problem that you are not calling the lambda, you are instead passing it as an argument to `erase`. By adding a pair of parentheses we can instead call the lambda to and pass it's return value to `erase`.

```
listIntegers.erase([&listIntegers]() {
    // Added & here ^
    return std::find(listIntegers.begin(), listIntegers.end(), 40);
}());
//^ Call the lambda
```

Comment: sorry - missed the call of the lambda! It works of course! thank you!